# Gitlab Runner unable to assume IAM role --The config profile (default) could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using EC2 to create a gitlab runner.
The runner is registering without any problem.
I am trying to assign a role to the ec2 using the userdata. Here is the code --

```
cat << EOF >> /home/gitlab-runner/.aws/config
[default]
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/gitlabrunner
credential_source=Ec2InstanceMetadata
region=us-east-1
EOF
```

I am able to attach the runner to a Gitlab Project. But when I am trying to run any pipeline I am getting the following error -

```
aws --version
aws-cli/2.13.0 Python/3.11.4 Linux/4.14.328-248.540.amzn2.x86_64 exe/x86_64.ubuntu.22 prompt/off
aws s3 ls
```

> The config profile (default) could not be found***

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: what do you see when you run `aws configure list`?

Comment: @ArpitJain, aws configure list is not showing the profile name. Any thoughts on how to fix ? here is the out put --sh-4.2$ aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************GUVD         iam-role
secret_key     ****************1fLo         iam-role
    region                us-east-1             imds

Comment: @ArpitJain did not work. My solution used to work great until few months back when I tried last. Unable to figure why the profile is not getting set, The keys are coming fine from the role.

Comment: @ArpitJain The role is getting attached to the instance without any problem. I am able to log into the aws instance and run aws s3 ls .It is the gitlab_runner  because the pipelines are failing with the error above when I run the same command using the gitlab ci file

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, any update?